# fabric-samples: Failed to generate orderer genesis block

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I trying to build the first-network using fabric samples.
when i run ./byfn.sh -m generate, each time this error appears

```
./byfn.sh: line 367:  1970 Segmentation fault      configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block

+ res=139
+ set +x

Failed to generate orderer genesis block...
```

Any help would be great appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

fixed.

Using bootstrap.sh downloaded a wrong version of configtxgen.

download the bin folder manually from https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/releases/org/hyperledger/fabric/hyperledger-fabric/ solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can run the bootstrap.sh script with a specified version:
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 2.0.0 1.4.4 0.4.18
This will download and install all the binaries required for Fabric 2.0.0, Fabric CA 1.4.4 and third party docker images 0.4.18
This solution worked for me.